# How would I check if a prompt is a string/number/boolean

Tags: javascript, html, string, numbers, boolean

So here's some background info; I am currently building a console app (where you can do `print()` and other things). So essentially I am making a programming language with **`JavaScript`**. What I am doing is that if the user type a command (I am doing a simple command; print()). It brings up a prompt to type either a `boolean`, `string`, or `number` depending on if they did `print(boolean)`, `print(number)`, etc. How can I check if the input the user typed in the prompt is a string, boolean, or number (I am storing the prompt in a variable)?

Comment: You'll need to show some code of what you have currently.

Comment: How are you getting user input?  `window.prompt` always returns a `String`.

Comment: Don't edit the word "Answered" into question titles. The green tick is sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`parseInt()` Converts only as much of the string as it can before the first invalid character, not the whole string. So parstInt("123abc") is 123.

If you use parseInt() on your variable and it returns nothing that would be a way to tell if its not an integer.